# facebook integration in android , post photos from all accounts

Tags: android, facebook, image

i have added facebook to my android app to share images and now the thing is that sharing can be done only from my facebook account, whenever i try and login from another account i cannot post any image this is the code snippet that i use . any help is appreciated
  `

```
Request uploadRequest = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(
                Session.getActiveSession(), bmp, new Request.Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                Toast.makeText(FacebookUpload.this,
                "Photo uploaded successfully",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

`

there is a part lyk this

```
`public void postImage() {
    if (checkPermissions()) {
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        String filename = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
        try {

            FileInputStream is = this.openFileInput(filename);
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Request uploadRequest = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(
                Session.getActiveSession(), bmp, new Request.Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        Toast.makeText(FacebookUpload.this,
                                "Photo uploaded successfully",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        File dir = getFilesDir();
                        File file = new File(dir, "bitmap.png");
                        file.delete();


                    }
                });


        // post on user's wall.
        Bundle params =uploadRequest.getParameters();
        Random rand = new Random();
        int rndInt = rand.nextInt(3)+1;
        if(rndInt==1)
        params.putString("name", "download Chummi-Lalli Mobile App from https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.interactive8.readmestories");
        else if(rndInt==2)
        params.putString("name","Send gifts to your loved ones from www.ekhudol.com");

        else if(rndInt==3)
            params.putString("name","Chummilalli brought to you by www.3leafsolutions.co.in");
        else
            params.putString("name","Chummilalli brought to you by www.3leafsolutions.co.in");
        uploadRequest.setParameters(params);
        uploadRequest.executeAsync();
    } 

    else 
        requestPermissions();



}`
```

n whenever i use another account i my code always goes to this else part requestPermission(), why am i redirected here always, everything works fine when i use my own facebook account

Comment: I guess, you might made some logical mistake. check your code twice before the image get upload.

Comment: @Hari Ram can you give me a clue as to where i should check , i have made the app available to all users from Facebook developer page, isn't this ought to be enough, if there is a problem then it should not work whichever account i log in from ryt??

Comment: Hi, show me full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was really simple, i had to do nothing but just submit my app to fb, i didnt know about this step on the developer website, i figured it out and now my app works just fine, thanks though